# how generate access token to my dotnet API?

Tags: authentication, .net-core, entity

I Have a API Dotnet core and i need a token to access the routes of application. I see the Identity Server Documentation but i cant recive the token.
I can receive the token via client request (front) but I need execute only the back-end aplication and this way the authentication need be by Entity Server. How can I do this?

[The token to authentication via swagger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9olxJ.png)

Comment: I see https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endpoints/authorize.html but I do not understand

Comment: Are you using three different projects. One for identity server, the other for your api and the 3rd for your API consumer? 
Does API need the user to be authenticated or it just needs to be called in c# code? 
What type of grant are you using? 
It would be great if you can explain the use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly invoke the `token endpoint` to get a token from the backend using `client_credentials` grant type. It should give the JWT you want. (https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endpoints/token.html#example)

Try the following example request:

```
POST /connect/token
CONTENT-TYPE application/x-www-form-urlencoded

    client_id=client1&
    client_secret=secret&
    grant_type=client_credentials&
    code=hdh922
```

Answer (score 0):

For the backend, use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer`.
Configure the service with authentication:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = Configuration["Authorization:Issuer"];
        options.Audience = Configuration["Authorization:Audience"];
    });
```

Curity provides a complete example for how to validate a JWT using .NET core: https://curity.io/resources/learn/dotnet-api/